# Google Sheets IFS and TRIM SPLIT reads only first thing that it finds

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of textbooks, and each textbook has its set of subject and target age, the thing is, that I need a formula in a column that checks, if subject contains AP or A Level, then it should also contain College Prep, and target age should be 16+. If subject contains College Prep but not AP or A Level, then target age should also be 16+.

The thing is that a book can have College Prep but not AP or A Level, but a book that has AP or A Level needs to also have College Prep on "Subject", if this is correct, then it should return "Good", if is not correct (example: having AP or A Level but not college prep) then it should return "Bad".

I must admit that this is somewhat high end for me, I thought of using IFS and TRIM SPLIT and this somewhat works but only reads the first subject on the cell.

I made a public sample sheet, feel free to edit it as needed, and thanks in advance!

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zKkq8crWGFTdHoIOLu2mJfrKRqr_8mKPwItWL54QbU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In G2 I entered

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B), if(regexmatch(B2:B, "(AP|A Level)?.*college prep"), "Good", "Bad"),))
```

See if that works for you?